# Is there a way to control the default pixel sizes of images exported from RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am producing many images with R graphics.

I am using RStudio.

RStudio has "Save plot as Image" and "Save plot as PDF" options.

However, the default size of the plot window seems to be controlled by the interface.  If I resize the windows and panes, the plot resizes, and sometimes loses important data.

Is there some environment variable that controls the default number of pixels in the plots?

Comment: change the width / height parameters when saving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USe the `pdf`, `tiff`, `png`, etc... devices. For instance

```
pdf("my_plot.pdf", height=6, width=8, units="in", res=300)
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
dev.off()
```

In this example, the image will be 300 x 6 pixels high and 300 x 8 pixels wide.